# What is the difference between MonoTouch and MonoDevelop?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

On main page there is MonoDevelop IDE, and MonoTouch (IDE?)

What is the difference? Are they two separate IDE's? With different features?

Comment: I'm guessing with those names, there's only one difference  :D

Answer (score 3):

MonoDevelop is the free cross-platform Mono IDE.  It can be used with Mono, MonoTouch, MonoDroid, MonoMac, etc.

MonoTouch is the commercial SDK that exposes the iOS API for use with C#.

Answer (score 0):

[MonoTouch vs MonoDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#MonoDevelop)  From the Wiki:

> Unlike Mono applications MonoTouch
>   "Apps" are compiled down to machine
>   code targeted specifically at the
>   Apple iPhone. This is necessary
>   because the iPhone kernel prevents
>   just-in-time compilers from executing
>   on the device.